# Print an array while alternating with the first and last (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment where I have to print a double array containing these numbers:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

like this

1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4

So the first and last should be alternating from the beginning of the array and the ending of the array.

I understand that the output can be confusing, but whats happening is that the first element should print (1), then the last element(7), then it must go back to the beginning and print the following element (3), then go back to the end and print the following element in the end (6) etc.

Here is my code so far:

```
    public static void print(double [] a){
    int l = a.length-1;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
      if(a[i] == a[l]){
        System.out.print(a[i]);
        break;
      }
      System.out.print(a[i]+", "+a[l--]+", ");
    }
  }
```

The code works but only if the size of the array is odd. I want to make sure this code works will all types of sized arrays.. Please help

Comment: This is one of those *rare* cases in which having code is actually harming the question.  How did you write this out on paper for odd arrays?  What does that logic look like?  Then we can strike on a solution from there.

Comment: hint: You're trying to work from the beginning and the end until you meet in the middle, but what if you don't meet? What if both ends just pass on by each other?

Comment: @watchme:  Work from the outside in.

Comment: What happens using this code if you input the numbers "1 2 3 2 1"?

Comment: @watchme:  Not using this exact code.  It'd probably print 1 and then break, which would be a bug.

Answer (score 3):

The rules here are fairly simple:

- Print the first element.
- Print the last element.
- Do not print the same element twice.

In terms of the array, you treat this as a bite-sized problem.

- Print the first index.
- Print the last index.
- Increment the pointer to the first index.
- Decrement the pointer to the last index.
- If the two points are the same, break - you're done.

In terms of code, that would look like this.  Note that in Java, you are permitted to declare multiple variables in your loop and use them in your expression later on.

```
int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1};
// i shouldn't advance beyond the first half of the list.
// j shouldn't advance beyond the second half of the list.
for(int i = 0, j = values.length - 1; i <= values.length/2 && j >= values.length/2; i++, j--) {
    // i and j are at the same point - just print it and call it good.
    if(i == j) {
        System.out.print(values[i]);
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.print(values[i] + " ");
        System.out.print(values[j] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was so simple yet I over complicated it. I had done this, but I did it in 2 nested loops. I realize my mistake happened in the if statement because I compared the element in i and j rather than the position itself. Thank you for your help and clarification.

Answer (score 2):

A. Try `i <= l` - it will take care of the even/odd lengths

B. Compare indicies and not the values, you need them till the middle of the array `i>=a.length/2`

```
public static void print(double [] a) {
    int l = a.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= l; i++, l--) {
        if (i>=a.length/2) {
            System.out.print(a[i]);
            break;
        }
        System.out.print(a[i] + ", " + a[l] + ", ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void print(double [] a) { 
 int l = a.length-1;  
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){ 
 if(i ==l){  
System.out.print(a[i]); 
break;
    }  else if (i>l ){ 
break; 
} 
System.out.print(a[i]+", "+a[l--]+", "); 
    }
```

Please try this .. it would helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] asd = {"john", "Peter", "Niki"};
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(asd);
    ArrayDeque<String> names = new ArrayDeque<>(list);

    while (names.size() > 2){
        System.out.println(names.pollFirst());
        System.out.println(names.pollLast());
    }
```

You can use ArrayDeque instead and simly use the pollFirst and pollLast methods.